# WebDriverIO browser.Click couldn't find element in Chrome and Running fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am using **WebdriverIO** with **CucumberJS** to do testing.
The code below works fine in Firefox, but I'm getting errors in Chrome, shows `element is not clickable`. I am looking for solution in JavaScript.

```
this.Then('I click on View Coupon Details button on a random coupon', () => {
    const randomElement = getRandomIndex(couponsCount);
    assert.ok(coupons.value[randomElement].element('.print-coupon').click('a'));
});
```

`coupons` is an array of `WebElements`. I am trying to click on **View Coupon detail** button.

[image]

**Sample Page:** 
http://www.princefrederickdodge.com/coupons.htm

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: can you also add the view of your project that you are testing, sometimes it is hard to reach nested divs

Comment: I noticed that there is a modal/popup in your page, while opening the page. You should take care of that one at first then you can interact with items on the page

Comment: I am testing it locally disabling all the pop-ups, but still facing the same issue. I have added a different site with no pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Try use an browser pause before your code

```
browser.pause(2000);
```

Sometimes this happens because of chrome delay. Always it works for me.

More: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html

Comment: Why do you suggest using browser.pause() which is bad practice in many cases?

Wdio has more suitable methods like waitForVisible, waitForEnabled, etc.

Comment: Yes, is a bad practice but you can try, for see if have worked. Sometimes I have to use like this becouse of chrome

Comment: Adding browser.pause didn't help. Still getting same error.`</a> is not clickable at point (164, 635). Other element would receive the click: `

Answer (score 0):

In the first way you can copy 99% the xpath/css selector from the inspector and .click will always work then. If not there 2 alternatives

If you run scripts localhost and you have access you can do

```
.execute(function(a, b, c, d) {
$('#button').click();
return a + b + c + d;
}, 1, 2, 3, 4).then(function(ret) {
// node.js context - client and console are available
log(ret.value); // outputs: 10
});
```

or with this way. the mouse will be pressed and release. You can find the right place if you make rightclick with webdriver.io to know where your coordinates are.

```
.moveToObject('#button', 0, -103)
.buttonDown()
.moveToObject('#button', 0, -104)
.buttonUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are better ways to do this, I am using, getLocation() and scroll to the location of the button to make it visible in viewport and then click it.

```
this.Then('I click on View Coupon Details button on a random coupon', () => {
    const randomElement = getRandomIndex(couponsCount);
    const pos = coupons.value[randomElement].getLocation();
    browser.scroll(pos.x, pos.y);
    browser.pause(200); // we can use waitforVisible .print-coupon as well
    assert.ok(coupons.value[randomElement].element('.print-coupon').click('a'));
});
```

Comment: can you please add more description regarding your answer?